# How to show a dropdown menu filter selected value made with a glob function after form is submitted?

Tags: php, html

I am working on a dropdown menu as part of a php form. The menu itself works fine but doesn't remain on the selected option of the menu once it is filtered.

[image: Dropdown menu]

Here is my code.

```
<?php
    $filter=$_POST['filter'];   
    echo $filter;
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">  
    <select name="filter" id="menu">
        <option value="">All Genres</option>
        <?php    
            $files=glob('*',GLOB_ONLYDIR);
            for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
                echo '<option value="'.$files[$i].'">'.$files[$i].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the selected element matches any of the files and mark it as selected with the attribute `selected` when creating the option list:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
    $attr = '';
    if ($files[$i] == $filter) {
        $attr = ' selected="selected"';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$files[$i].'"'. $attr .'>'.$files[$i].'</option>';
}
```